# selenium IDE: how to testing the ? or * as part of the text, not as wildcard match?

Tags: special-characters, target, selenium-ide, string-matching

May I ask how to verify a text with special character ? or * as part of the text, not as a wildcard match of the text?

I am using selenium IDE to verify a browser pop up alert.    The pop up alert message contain a special character "This will change the globe setting, is it ok?".  When I use the VerifyConfirmation command with target as "This will change the globe setting, is it ok?", the VerifyConfirmation command will fail and error message is "[error] Active value 'This will change the globe setting, is it ok?' did not match 'This will change the globe setting, is it ok?'.   It seems like selenium see the last character ? as wildcard.    I have also tried to use the exact:This will change the globe setting, is it ok? but it does not work too.

May I ask is there anyway to test the last character as ?, not a wildcard?

Thanks

Kam

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is related to the question mark. First off, the ? in glob patterns is used to match any single character, so a real question mark would match the special question mark. Secondly, I've seen the sort of error message you're seeing quite often. It is almost always related to there being more or fewer white spaces in the argument specified than in the page.  For example, "abcdef ghijklmn" doesn't match "abcdef  ghijklmn" but IDE's error message will show both strings with a single space.

Try a pattern of just

*setting*

to see if it matches. If it does, then start adding one word at a time until the test fails.

OR, just look at the source so you can copy/paste the correctly spaced string into the Target field of IDE.